# A text must be provide to Barcode before drawing in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, zend-framework, barcode

I use zend libraries to generate barcode in codeigniter.

This is my controller :

```
$this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode'); 
    $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode'); //nomor id barcode
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text'=>$barcode), array())->render();

    $imageName = $barcode.'.jpg';
    $imagePath = 'barcode/'; // penyimpanan file barcode
     imagejpeg($imageResource, $imagePath.$imageName); 
    $pathBarcode = $imagePath.$imageName; 

    $kd_barang = $this->input->post('kd_barang');

    $pathBarcode = $this->input->post('barcode');



    $editdata=array(
        /*Nama Field => $Nama Variabel*/

        'barcode' => $pathBarcode
    );


    /*Primary Key Sebagai Kunci*/
    $where=array(
        'kd_barang'=>$kd_barang
    );
    /*Mengambil Function Dari Model*/
    $this->m_operator->aksi_update_barang($where,$editdata,'barang');
    redirect('c_op/index');
```

This is my view :

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(). 'index.php/c_op/aksi_editbarang'; ?>" method="post">

    <center>

    <table border="1">
        <?php 

        foreach ($edit->result() as $c){?>
        <tr>
            <td>Kode Barang</td>
            <!-- Primary Key Sebagai Kunci -->
            <td><input type="text" name="kd_barang" value="<?php echo $c->kd_barang ?>" readonly></input></td>

        <tr>
            <td>Barcode</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="barcode" value="<?php echo $c->kd_barang ?>" readonly><?php echo $c->barcode;?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">UPDATE</button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

    </center>

</form>
```

But the barcode could not be drawn because it said "A text must be provide to Barcode befeore drawing". But i have already declare that the text for $barcode is $kd_barang.
It's saved to the database but as a text, not as image. Please help me.

Comment: `var_dump($barcode);` what is it?

Comment: i deleted the redirect and replace it with var_dump($pathBarcode), the image show up , but not saved to the database

Comment: so your problem is no longer: "A text must be provide to Barcode befeore drawing"

Comment: but i open the image path on folder barcode, the image is still said a text must be provide to barcode before drawing

Comment: so again I must ask var_dump(**$barcode**); what is it?

Comment: and the reason why the path isn't saving is because you define `$pathBarcode = $this->input->post('barcode');` after `$pathBarcode = $imagePath.$imageName;`

Comment: it's null, and there is an error message, undefined variable barcode

Comment: there is your problem. that is why you should always validate your input

Comment: why foreach? is this your actual view that you are using to submit? are you aware that a form doesn't work that way? for example if you want to have multiple inputs under the same name in the same form (and from the loop if you have more than 1 result you will have duplicate names), then you need to either make it an array by adding `[]` name and processing on backend with loop or you need to put the form open and close within the loop so each form submit is seperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason you aren't getting the `$barcode` value. I suspect the view you posted isn't directly related.

The following code will validate input to some degree and fix the path issue.

```
    $this->load->library('zend');
    $this->zend->load('Zend/Barcode');
    $barcode = $this->input->post('barcode'); //nomor id barcode
    $kd_barang = $this->input->post('kd_barang');
    if (is_null($barcode) || is_null($kd_barang)) {
        show_error('Missing parameters');
    }
    // make barcode
    $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'image', array('text' => $barcode), array())->render();
    $imageName = $barcode . '.jpg';
    $imagePath = 'barcode/'; // penyimpanan file barcode
    imagejpeg($imageResource, $imagePath . $imageName);
    $pathBarcode = $imagePath . $imageName;
    $editdata = array(
        'barcode' => $pathBarcode
    );
    $where = array(
        'kd_barang' => $kd_barang
    );
    $this->m_operator->aksi_update_barang($where, $editdata, 'barang');
    //redirect('c_op/index'); commented out for debugging
```

Comment: wait, you want to store an image in your database rather than the oath? why are you writing it to a file then? is your column a BLOB? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: and the other 3 questions?